# Open file in C linux

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I am using C to open a file for reading. I have this code :

```
fp = fopen("./settings.cfg","r");
if (fp != NULL)
    printf("OK");
else
    printf("ERROR");
```

but I always get an error.

The file is located in the folder where the executable resides. I have tried writing only "settings.cfg". What might be the problem?

Comment: Use `perror` rather than `printf` so you at least get an idea of _why_ it is failing.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Please check whether the file is present in the path from which you are executing the code or ensure you give absolute path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `perror()` to have the library itself tell you what, if anything, is wrong.

```
fp = fopen("./settings.cfg", "r");
if (fp != NULL)
    printf("OK\n");
else perror("fopen");
```

Comment: fopen: No such file or directory

Comment: File is not present in the path where you are running this program.

Comment: If you're on a POSIX system, try [`getcwd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) next.

Comment: I think that must be `fopen("settings.cfg","r");` I haven't unix for test it now.

Answer (score 3):

You are opening the file in the "current directory", not "in the folder where the executable is".

In fact, unix has no easy way to find that particular folder; in Linux you could readlink() the /proc/[your pid]/exe link to find the executable and strip off the filename portion -- that will work in many cases, but there are some fringe cases like hardlinks that will make it fail.

Answer (score 1):

From which directory do you run the program? It won't have the directory where it resides as the current directory, it will be inherited from the environment.

Could also be rights, that the file is owned by someone else and you don't have read rights.

Also double-check the filename. This sounds obvious, but do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If file you are trying to open is in the same directory of your C compiled file, you must simply do

```
fp = fopen("settings.cfg","r");
if (fp != NULL)
  printf("OK");
else
  printf("ERROR");
```

without the initial " ./ " at the file's name